# trying to make a login page by using retrofit library and rest API in android studio with login API but login failed

Tags: android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2, rest, retrofit2.6

```
   package com.example.androidapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity  {

EditText  username, password;
Button btnLogin;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    username    = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    password = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    btnLogin      = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Username / Password Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                //proceed to login
                login();
            }
        }
    });
}


    public void login(){
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
        loginRequest.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
        loginRequest.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

        Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall = ApiClient.getUserService().userLogin(loginRequest);
        loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override

            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

                Log.d("@sid","res"+response.code());

                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    final LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Permission2.class).putExtra("data",loginResponse.getUsername()));
                        }
                    },700);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Throwable "+t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Whenever I am trying to make a login page for my application, its showing login failed and its not passing intent as well as unable to pass the data on 2nd page of my application. I am helpless and not getting any idea to resolve this issue. 
I request you to kindly check my above coding and let me know if I have done anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please reformat the pasted code to be more readable.

Second of all - did you add Internet permission to AndroidManifest file?

Third of all - you can print what's wrong to log, for example:

```kotlin
Log.d("LoginError", "${response.errorBody.string()}");
```

Also did you follow some kind of tutorial on how to use Retrofit? Maybe follow some easy tutorial to get idea how to work this out :)

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. Can you please send me the rest Api coding for the same? I would be thankful to you.

Yes I have added the internet permission to android manifest file.

Comment: Sir I am new to it and hence, I dont know how to reformat the proper coding here.

Comment: No problem, instead of this code in onResponse: ```Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ``` add the code I posted and check Logcat why there is an error in response and post it here :)

Comment: 2020-06-16 14:40:01.884 14472-14472/net.larntech.loginregister D/@sid: res404
2020-06-16 14:40:07.811 14472-14472/net.larntech.loginregister D/@sid: res404
2020-06-16 14:40:09.839 14472-14472/net.larntech.loginregister D/@sid: res404
2020-06-16 14:40:10.351 14472-14472/net.larntech.loginregister D/@sid: res404
2020-06-16 14:40:10.401 14472-14472/net.larntech.loginregister D/@sid: res404
2020-06-16 14:40:10.543 14472-14472/net.larntech.loginregister D/@sid: res404
2020-06-16 14:40:11.296 14472-14472/net.larntech.loginregister D/@sid: res404

Comment: Sir, I have reformatted the coding again, can you please check now? Also, Please check the logcat error above

Comment: Are you sure it's this error? If 'res404' is the error, you probably have bad address because 404 means 'Not Found'. So check the URL in 'userLogin' method

Comment: Sir, please be online, let me check, I will inform you in few minutes.

Comment: Also the thing you can put in your okHttp client (remember to remove it for release version of the app) is HttpLoggingInterceptor. With that you will have nice & clean logging for your requests and responses: https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: Let Me check, I will be back to you :)

Comment: Sir, its for kotlin, I need it for Java coding, please provide me any reference link if you have.

Comment: Come, you can't change it to Java by yourself? Log.d("LoginError", "Error: " + response.errorBody.string());